# creating basic navigation in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am a complete noob to backbone and decided to try and create a web page or two based using backbone as a structure.  My first task is to create a basic navigation.
My page lives here http://dalydd.com/projects/backbone.html
here is my javascript thus fur to create that one little navigation item

```
(function($){
  var NavigationItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      name: '',
      href: '',
      last: false,
      id: ''
    },

    initialize: function() {

    }
  });

  var home = new NavigationItem({name: 'home', href: '/home', id:'home'});
  var about = new NavigationItem({name:'about', href: '/about'});
  var contact = new NavigationItem({name:'contact', href: '/contact', last:true});

  var TopNav = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: NavigationItem,
  });

  var topNav = new TopNav();

  NavView = Backbone.View.extend({  
    el : $('ul'), 

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render'); 
      this.render();  
    },  

    render : function() {
      var self = this;
      $(this.el).append("<li><a href="+home.get('href')+">"+home.get('name')+"</a></li>")
    }

  });

  var navView = new NavView();

})(jQuery);
```

My question(s) is how can i loop through each instantiated nav item and append it to the ul element w/o writing each one out

My other question is can you use backbone without data-binding your scripts, data-binding seems like obtrusive javascript in a way.  Also does one need to become an expert in underscore.js in order to use backbone properly.  Underscore just seems like a bunch of predefined functions - doesn't jQuery offer some of the same functions as utility functions? so why even use underscore is because of the data binding?  can you use backbone w/o data-binding everything?  I'm having a difficult time learning backbone because I feel like it mimics a classical language instead of using something like Object.create() like Douglas Crockford uses.  Are there any resources out there that just build a basic page using backbone?  I know it's not intended for small applications but I'm still trying to figure out how it all works.

Again any help/resources is appreciated.  I just started working for a large corporation and they are looking to implement an MVC framework for javascript and backbone seems the ideal choice but I am struggling thus far to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone provides Collections for this matter. Any Backbone View can hold a Model or a Collection. In your example you could build a collection like this:

```
var NavigationCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : NavigationItem
});
```

Then, you would create the collection and append all of the items:

```
var navCollection = new NavigationCollection();
navCollection.add(home);
navCollection.add(about);
navCollection.add(content);
```

and then you can make a view which just displays it all:

```
var navView = new NavView({
    collection : navCollection
});
```

being this view something like:

```
var NavView = Backbone.View.extend({  
    el : $('ul'), 

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render'); 
        this.render();  
    },  

    render : function() {
        this.collection.each(function (item) {
            this.$el.append("<li><a href=" + item.get("href") + ">" + item.get("name") + "</a></li>");
        }, this);
        return this; // remember this for chaining
    }

});
```

You could have a view for displaying each of the individual items (and a `subviews` attribute, so you can refer to them) or even a template which iterates over this collection.

Comment: Thanks Meta - this was a huge help - only thing i changed was
var navView = new NavView({
    collection : navCollection
});
as you had NavigationView which confused me but I figured it out and I put it below extending the extended view

Comment: Yeah, sorry ^^ It was a typo. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

> Underscore just seems like a bunch of predefined functions - doesn't jQuery offer some of the same functions as utility functions? so why even use underscore is because of the data binding? can you use backbone w/o data-binding everything?

Underscore doesn't deal with the DOM, only with JavaScript. The two are orthogonal.

- Underscore is a backbone dependency , you need it to make it work.
- jQuery/Zepto is needed if you need to work with the DOM ( and ajax ).
- Underscore is used in models and collections at least , whether you use it directly or not.

> I'm having a difficult time learning backbone because I feel like it mimics a classical language instead of using something like Object.create() like Douglas Crockford uses.

- You need to use the library API when required , or use another lib. Backbone uses prototypal inheritance when Object.create is classical inheritance. JavaScript allows both.

My point is you don't need to use every feature of backbone, but you need to use the basic required features in order to make it work.

Comment: thanks for your insight Camus.  I feel Object.create is more prototypal and less pseudoclassical like Backbone (maybe you just got them mixed up) when using backbone i use new alot unlike .create
if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
    Object.create = function (o) {
        function F() {}
        F.prototype = o;
        return new F();
    };
}
newObject = Object.create(oldObject);

here you are prototyping the built in Object in js.
also my point about jQuery is that it offers a lot of utility functions that don't necessarily have to use the DOM to work like .extend, .map, etc